# Formatting csv to allow numpy to make a data frame

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to read in this CSV file with numpy. I'm following [this tutorial](http://wiki.quantsoftware.org/index.php?title=QSTK_Tutorial_2) but my data is formatted differently to their example

[Here's a my csv data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29jmpbf6e_WZ2JYT3BxRFN1OGM)

and the code i'm using:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


na_data = np.loadtxt('BTC.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=2)
na_price = na_data[:, 3:4]
na_dates = np.str_(na_data[:, 0:1])

print na_price
print na_dates

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 09/08/2015
```

I need to format the date at the beginning, I've been following other peoples Q&A's online and realize i need something like this`pd.read_csv('BTC.csv', dayfirst=True, parse_dates=[0])`but can't figure out how to implement it.

Thank you for your time

EDIT: the data was originally taken [from here](http://cryptocoincharts.info/fast/period.php?pair=ETH-BTC&market=poloniex&time=alltime&resolution=1d), and I wrote a script to split each line. However from jezrael's comment, printing the data frame produces a format similar to this ! So maybe maybe I can just feed this text in directly to pandas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter `sep` as arbitary whitespace: `\s+` in function [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Date        low     open    close   high    BTC_vol 
08/08/2015  266     280.04  266.82  280.32  273.43  
09/08/2015  260.88  264     265.52  267.6   264.76  
10/08/2015  262.17  265.69  265.1   267.72  265.395 """
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True )
print df
#        Date     low    open   close    high  BTC_vol
#0 2015-08-08  266.00  280.04  266.82  280.32  273.430
#1 2015-08-09  260.88  264.00  265.52  267.60  264.760
#2 2015-08-10  262.17  265.69  265.10  267.72  265.395

print df.loc[2, 'Date']
#2015-08-10 00:00:00

print df.loc[2, 'close']
#265.1
```

If you want convert `pandas dataframe` to `numpy array` use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
print df.values
#[[Timestamp('2015-08-08 00:00:00') 266.0 280.04 266.82 280.32 273.43]
# [Timestamp('2015-08-09 00:00:00') 260.88 264.0 265.52 267.6 264.76]
# [Timestamp('2015-08-10 00:00:00') 262.17 265.69 265.1 267.72 265.395]]
```

EDIT:

You have to omit separator, because `sep=','` is a default value (thanks [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916412/formatting-csv-to-allow-numpy-to-make-a-data-frame#comment57570214_34916491)):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test/BTC.csv',parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)
print df.head()

          D     low   open   close     high  Unnamed: 5       BTC_vol  \
0 2015-08-08  266.00  280.04  266.82  280.32     273.430  29915.158940   
1 2015-08-09  260.88  264.00  265.52  267.60     264.760  16578.024530   
2 2015-08-10  262.17  265.69  265.10  267.72     265.395  10780.629240   
3 2015-08-11  264.81  265.09  269.57  270.30     267.330   9817.758063   
4 2015-08-12  265.80  269.30  269.84  273.75     269.570  14290.615450   

   USD_vol  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  
0  8116830           0  281.312854  
1  4382630           0  279.808773  
2  2856790           0  278.407937  
3  2619460           0  277.566229  
4  3848950           0  276.830398
```

Comment: Ok so this is interesting, firstly thanks for the reply, it's appreciated. I copied the sample text from a spreadsheet but it didn't format properly, I have copied in a direct link to the data.

Comment: you could just ommit `sep` because `sep=','` is a default value